# iptables - Newly added rule disappears in a few seconds Xenial Server

Tags: iptables, firewall

I need to add a rule to open Mosquitto port:

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp --dport 1883 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1883
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2812
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:xmpp-client
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5555
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:http-alt:8099
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:4380:4400
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:17443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:17441
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:socks
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1443
ACCEPT     all  --  appscale-image0      anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

A few seconds later the newly added line disappears as below:

```
$  sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2812
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:xmpp-client
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5555
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:http-alt:8099
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:4380:4400
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:17443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:17441
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:socks
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1443
ACCEPT     all  --  appscale-image0      anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Any insight into this mysterious disappearance? There is no cron job running. ufw is disabled. I'm not sure how to check what underlying firewall service is running.

Comment: How are you setting your iptables rules ? Ulness you are running a service of some sort to restore your rules probably a bug hard to tell from what you posted.

Comment: Just using the iptables -I command as in the post. I would do a iptables-save if the rule didn't vanish in 5s or so. I'm not sure what underlying service iptables is talking to.

Comment: I'm on a fresh install of Xenial server

Comment: As @bodhi.zazen asked, how are you setting the other iptables rules? i.e. how does the ssh ACCEPT rule get entered? There must be something you are not telling us, because a fresh install of 16.04 server will not clobber your rules.

Comment: Exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 18.4. 
iptables -N TEST
and after a few seconds (30-60?) it disappears. ufw disabled.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that you have the nftables package installed? I had a similar problem at debian, which was caused by nftables also modifying chains out of the box. Both that package and modern iptables write to the same kernel tables.